# Show $\gcd(a,b)=1$ implies $\varphi(a\cdot b)=\varphi(a)\cdot\varphi(b)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm, totient-function, multiplicative-function

> This means that if $\gcd(m, n) = 1$, then $φ(mn) = φ(m) φ(n)$. (Outline of proof: let $A, B, C$ be the sets of nonnegative integers, which are, respectively, coprime to and less than $m, n$, and $mn$; then there is a bijection between $A × B$ and $C$, by the Chinese remainder theorem.)

I also saw this on wiki page of [Euler's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function), but I didn't get the idea$\dots$

My attempts:

By [FTA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic) we have:
$$a=p_1^{\alpha_1}\cdots p_n^{\alpha_n}$$
$$b=q_1^{\beta_1}\cdots q_m^{\beta_m}$$
Since $\gcd(a,b)=1$, have $p_i\neq q_j$, where $i\in[1,n],j\in[1,m]$, implies:
$$a\cdot b=p_1^{\alpha_1}\cdots p_n^{\alpha_n}\cdot q_1^{\beta_1}\cdots q_m^{\beta_m}$$
From this:
\begin{align}
&~~~~~~\varphi(a\cdot b)\\
&=\varphi (p_1^{\alpha_1}\cdots p_n^{\alpha_n}\cdot q_1^{\beta_1}\cdots q_m^{\beta_m})\tag*{(1)}\\
&=a\cdot b(1-\frac{1}{p_1})\cdots (1-\frac{1}{p_n})(1-\frac{1}{q_1})\cdots (1-\frac{1}{q_m})\tag*{(2)}\\
&=a(1-\frac{1}{p_1})\cdots (1-\frac{1}{p_n})\cdot b (1-\frac{1}{q_1})\cdots (1-\frac{1}{q_m})\tag*{(3)}\\
&=\varphi (p_1^{\alpha_1}\cdots p_n^{\alpha_n})\cdot\varphi(q_1^{\beta_1}\cdots q_m^{\beta_m})\tag*{(4)}\\
&=\varphi(a)\cdot\varphi(b)\tag*{(5)}
\end{align}

Is this proof valid, since I saw the proof of [Euler's product formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wkdih.png)$($used in step $(2))$ seems like also using this property, then if I use Euler's product formula to prove this property, it seems like a little circular, or is there other approaches $?$

Comment: When you say "recursive", I think you mean "circular".

Comment: @J.G. ah$\dots$ yes thats what I mean, thanks

Comment: Some proofs that Euler's function is multiplicative: [What's the proof that the Euler totient function is multiplicative?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/192452) or [Very elementary proof of that Euler's totient function is multiplicative](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/999563).

Comment: The formula $\varphi(n)=n\prod\left(1-\frac1p\right)$ can be shown also without using the multiplicative property - for example, using principle of inclusion and exclusion. (And I think I saw also some proofs using induction.) You can check this question: [Proving that $\varphi(n)=n\prod (1-1/p)$ without using multiplicativity](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1298386).

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is indeed correct, and note that it is exceedingly similar to a standard proof that can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/292519/1026367).

Also, check out this cool [visual proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/999563/very-elementary-proof-of-that-eulers-totient-function-is-multiplicative?noredirect=1&lq=1) that uses very little algebra.

Anyways, nice work finding this proof!